# What does the 'Download Build Artifacts' actually do?

Tags: download, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I've added the necessary tasks to run the 'Download Build Artifacts', however, I cannot see it downloaded anywhere. I am now left wondering what this task actually does. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

**It downloads files to an agent**. Moreover to make download valid you need to select what to download:

[image]

So if on the agent you don't see any downloads, maybe you selected a wrong matching pattern or selected a wrong artifact name.

Answer (score 0):

you can see it downloaded in VSTS agent folder(if deploying on virtual machine otherwise it gets downloaded on Agent Server only)
go to path C:\VSTSAgent_work\r1\a
you will see all your artifacts here

Comment: Is this the same as Publish Artifact? Publish Artifact provides a direct link to the artifact in the build pipeline.